# gradient descent get different final parameters for different initial parameters for linear regression in matrix form

Tags: python, linear-regression, matrix-multiplication, gradient-descent

I wrote gradient descent for linear regression in matrix form but I got different final theta for different initial theta. I set a very small learning rate and large max iterations so I think all final theta should be similar.

This is my code for gradient descent algorithm

```
def loss(theta, X, y_obs):
    '''
    Calculates the loss for given X and y. 
    theta= Vector of weights
    dim(theta) = d+1
    
    X = Matrix of X with added bias units
    dim(X) = n x (d+1) 
    
    y = Vector of y true labels
    dim(y) = n
    
    where n is number of data points and d is number of features
    
    Returns predited labels y_hat, dim(y_hat) = n
    '''
    n = len(y_obs)
    y_hat = np.dot(X, theta.T)
    loss = np.mean((y_hat - y_obs) ** 2)   #Here is MSE loss
    return loss
    



def gradient_of_loss(theta, X, y_obs):
    '''
    The function should be different for different relationship between X and y_hat
    This function only works for linear regression
    
    Returns gradient of loss wrt theta dloss
    dim(dloss) = d+1
    '''
    n = len(y_obs)
    return 1.0/n * (theta.T @ X.T @ X - y_obs.T @ X)



def gradient_descent(X, y_obs, theta, learning_rate=0.01, max_iterations=100, epsilon=0.1):
    '''
    Returns
    1. the final theta vector, dim(theta) = d+1
    2. Whether it reaches max_iterations
    
    Terminates if loss <= epsilon or reach max number of iterations
    '''
    
    n = len(y_obs)
    num_iter = 0
    
        
    while (loss(theta, X, y_obs) > epsilon) and (num_iter <= max_iterations):
        theta = theta - learning_rate * gradient_of_loss(theta, X, y_obs)
        num_iter += 1
        
    return theta, (num_iter <= max_iterations)
```

This is my code to run it and comparison with analytical solution

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips["bias"] = 1
X = tips[["total_bill", "bias"]] #Shape (244, 2)
y_obs = tips["tip"] #Shape (244, 1)
theta, num_iter = gradient_descent(X, y_obs, np.asarray([0, 0]), learning_rate=0.0001, max_iterations=1000)

theta_hat = np.linalg.solve(X.T @ X, X.T @ y_obs)
theta_hat
```

Theta from analytical solution (theta_hat) is [0.1, 0.92] whereas theta from my algorithm is

[0.142852(total_bill) 0.021238(bias)] for theta = [0, 0]

[0.103287(total_bill) 0.961570(bias)] for theta = [1, 1]

[0.024156(total_bill) 2.842236(bias)] for theta = [3, 3]

etc.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `-2` here instead of 2? `return 2 * np.dot(np.mean(y_hat - y_obs), X)`

Comment: Thanks for finding the typo! I changed to -2 but still have similar results. Especially for the shape (244,2) theta

Comment: If X is a matrix of x values, why is it supposed to be (2,)?

Comment: Since `np.mean(y_hat - y_obs)` is a scalar, `np.dot(np.mean(y_hat - y_obs), X)` is the same as `X * np.mean(y_hat - y_obs)`. `theta = theta - learning_rate * gradient_of_loss(theta, X, y_obs)` then broadcasts to `(244,2)`. I think this should be enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: I did derivative directly to the second norm (MSE) in the gradient of loss function. I should first express MSE as dot product then take the derivative. The result is still not correct but the dimension matches.